# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask.dataframe'; 'dask' is not a package

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to merge two very large CSV files with Dask as an alternative to Pandas. I have installed Dask thorough `pip install "dask[dataframe]"`.

When running `import dask.dataframe as dd`, I am however receiving the feedback `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask.dataframe'; 'dask' is not a package`.

Several users seem to have had the same problem and were recommneded to install the module via Conda, which has not helped either in my case.

What is the reason for the module not being found?

Comment: Do you have a local file named `dask.py`?  Show us the output of this code: `import dask; print(dask.__file__)`

Comment: Thanks for the great input - that solved it. Yes one of the files was called `dask.py`.

Comment: :). This being a general kind of problem, I'm not sure it's worth it, but you may want to give your situation and solution as an answer for others.

Comment: Good point, let me summarise something as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user John Gordon mentioned, the reason for the error notification is that a  file within the same folder was named `dask.py`. Renaming the file solved the situation within seconds.

As a general rule/conclusion: is as advisable to not use .py file names that directly relate to Python modules.

Comment: lol. I'm a pretty experienced SDE at FANG company. Still got this wrong. Named my file dask.py to study dask. Seems to to happen to the best of us. Thx for answer.